# Warning message in command line

Tags: uefi, sudo

When I use 'sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade' command, everything is normal. But at the end of the process lines of messages appear

```
Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Systems on them will not be added to the GRUB boot configuration.
Check GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER documentation entry.
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
```

I want to know this is a problem about my laptop or is it normal.

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details; but you have provided a message I see on Debian (*saw it in fact today*) but not Ubuntu systems as Ubuntu carries patches that prevent users from experiencing it on *supported* systems.  What OS/release are you asking about?  FYI:  On Debian & other GNU/Linux the message is *normal* & I see when grub updates; on Ubuntu I never see it (*outside of a short period late 2021 to early 2022 on an alpha release before Ubuntu prevent it from occurring prior to beta*)

Comment: Os is Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Please add release details to your question; Ubuntu 22.04 LTS experienced the OS_PROBER  issue during the *alpha* stage (see https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2021-December/041769.html) but the issue was removed prior to Ubuntu *jammy* reaching *beta* via Ubuntu patches.  That is not expected; however it can be changed by users with `sudo` privileges to revert Ubuntu's patches on OS_PROBER  (other GNU/l.inux such as Debian I mentioned do not carry Ubuntu patches that reverse OS_PROBER defaults)